# 2D vector components

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors

Can  any equation with a vector e.g. velocity be used with just the horizontal or just the vertical components, I am thinking of equations like Newton's laws, conservation of linear momentum etc. So is it ok just to use one component rather then the whole value (if so why)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would only use a component of a vector **only if** you are interested in that component. We break vectors into components since it is easier to use the vectors in calculation.

For example: If you throw a ball, you might want to see how high it goes, or how far you can throw it. Here we use a component of the vector (either vertical or horizontal) without the need of the other component.

Comment: But these can be used with the laws stated and others (I.e. Just the 1 component)?

Comment: When you break a vector up into components, you create orthogonal vectors (in 2D space, vectors at right angles). Each of the orthogonal vectors can be used in calculations just like the original one.

Answer (score 0):

A vector is a variable which has 2 attributes - size and direction (unlike whats called scalar, which has only size - e.g energy).

In most Newton's 2nd law questions, you need to "break down" the direction attribute into 2 components - $x$ component and $y$ component - usually by a simple sin/cos function. Then you can calculate each component size, and then, usually by Pythagorean theorem, calculate the size of the vector, and its direction.